# How to program routed events like system present in WPF on my own?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, reverse-engineering, routed-events

WPF has this great architecture of routing the event. And even  the event does not have to be in the any particular object. like Button.Clicked can be handled in a parent Stackpanel. And you can stop it from routing or bubbling by using  e.Handled = true. How does it know how to route event. All of this unlike normal events. Everything about seems magical to me . i want know how create a system like this on my own in c#. Is there any design pattern that i should know about or any good blogs that explain this kind of architecture.?

Answer (score 1):

In your UI, each object has a reference to its parent, `Window <- Grid <- Button`, for example.

The simplest dispatch code would to start at the element where the event is triggered, and then let it bubble up until it's handled.

```
// Pseudocode
HandleLocally(sender, e);
if(!e.Handled) {
    Parent.HandleBubbledEvent(sender, e);
}
```

Of course, this is not how WPF does it - WPF is way more complex.
WPF [creates an "EventRoute"](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/ac9d1b7a6b0ee7c44fd2875a1174b820b3940619/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationCore/System/Windows/UIElement.cs#L2318) from the dependency object graph, and then invokes all the handlers in the route. Some handlers are invoked [even for events that are marked as handled](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/ae1790531c3b993b56eba8b1f0dd395a3ed7de75/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationCore/System/Windows/RoutedEventHandlerInfo.cs#L70).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a blog but the code of wpf elements is readable on [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Stack.cs,74647d237fc89a63,references).

**Edit:**

Sometime they explain how the element work like in [grid.cs line 488](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/Grid.cs).